# Check file is empty imagecreatefromgif - php

Tags: php, php-gd

I am displaying image from file using PHP. My code looks like this

```
$image = @imagecreatefromgif(../ProfileIcons/".$use);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);
imagestring($image,$font_size,14,4, $code, $text_color);

header('Content-Type: image/gif');
$kk = imagegif($image);

imagedestroy($image);
```

Here how do i check if the image present in `ProfileIcons/` is empty?

I have to put a condition such that

```
if (image is present in `ProfileIcons/`) 

   $image = @imagecreatefromgif(../ProfileIcons/".$use);

else (image is not present in the folder)

   $image = Show default image
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking into file_exists

```
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
// process image
} else {
// use default image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // check if file exist 
  if(file_exists('../ProfileIcons/'.$use.''))
  {// do what you like }else{//}
```